RNGoogleSignin not found - expo supabase auth
Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNGoogleSignin' could not be found.

I dont know why i this error is coming i have installed the package properly in expo app
i want to authentication use with google signin using supabase auth.

also have this error, I still haven't solved it, but it also happens with firebase when using the google-signin package. I found out that I can log into google without firebase/supabase and then use the ID you got from the login to log with firebase/supabase

As shown in this github issue, google login doesn't work within Expo Go. You will need to create a iOS or Android build to test google login.
Edit: Expo set up documentation also states this in the "Note" at the start of the page

Yes i got the solution.
I was using expo app and some feature are not supported in expo app so
I used android emulator using android studio and I was working absolutely fine
